# How to specify credentials for Bearer auth in Swagger-Net

Tags: .net, swagger

I'm migrating from Swashbuckle to Swagger-Net and need help with specifying user credentials to get a bearer token and auth with it.

Everything is working fine if I'll specify the bearer token explicitly, but I want a way to specifiy username, password and ClienId, then get a bearer token and include it in all requests.

In Swashbuckle I was able to achive it using this [article](https://stevemichelotti.com/customize-authentication-header-in-swaggerui-using-swashbuckle/). Is any way to make it working with Swagger-net other way than in article above?

**Upd:** I tried to use OAuth, I was able to authorize, but bearer token is not adding to each request. More over, if i press auth on method available authorizations are empty. What's wrong?

```
httpConfiguration
     .EnableSwagger(c =>
         {
            c.OAuth2("oauth2")
                .Flow("password")
                .TokenUrl("/token");

             c.OperationFilter<AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements>();
         });
     .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
         {
             c.EnableOAuth2Support("test-client-id", "test-realm", "Swagger UI");
         });
```

Comment: I think you should raise this with the swagger-ui team: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues  The team would likely want to know how your swagger.json looks like, so get an example ready

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I made it working. The issue was in wrong AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements filter: I specified Bearer instead oauth2 security

```
public class AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            // Correspond each "Authorize" role to an oauth2 scope
            var scopes = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline()
                .Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Instance)
                .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
                .SelectMany(attr => attr.Roles.Split(','))
                .Distinct();

            if (scopes.Any())
            {
                if (operation.security == null)
                    operation.security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();

                var oAuthRequirements = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    { "oauth2", scopes }
                };

                operation.security.Add(oAuthRequirements);
            }
        }
    }
```